# Objects not in getGlobalDescribe() (Scorecard, ScorecardMetric, ScorecardAssociation)

Tags: api, describesobject

i am confused why the objects Scorecard, ScorecardMetric, ScorecardAssociation arn't listed in the getGlobalDescribe() Map.

Documentation (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_schema.htm) says

> Returns a map of all sObject names (keys) to sObject tokens (values) for the standard and custom objects defined in your organization.

Either that is not true, or those objects arn't sObjects. What else are they? They are available as ObjectPermissions in Permissionsets and Profiles, so i assume they are sObjects.

So i checked if other objects, which are accesable in PermissionSets and Profiles, but arn't in the getGlobalDescribe()-Map. There are just those 3. 
Is this a documented special behavior or am i missing something out?

**EDIT:** Anonymous apex code to print objects which are accesible in the permissionsets but arn't included in the global describe.

```
Boolean printAllStandardAndCustomObjects = true;
Boolean printAllObjectsFromObjectPermissions = true;

Map <String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
List<String> schemas = new List<String>(schemaMap.keySet());
schemas.sort();

if(printAllStandardAndCustomObjects){
    System.debug('===============================');
    System.debug('ALL STANDARD AND CUSTOM OBJECTS');
    System.debug('===============================');
    for (String schema : schemas) {
        System.debug(schema);
    }
}

List<ObjectPermissions> objectPermissionsList = [
        SELECT SobjectType
        FROM ObjectPermissions
];
Set<String> accessibleObjects = new Set<String>();
for (ObjectPermissions objectPermissions : objectPermissionsList) {
    accessibleObjects.add(objectPermissions.SobjectType);
}
List<String> objectPermissions = new List<String>(accessibleObjects);
objectPermissions.sort();

if(printAllObjectsFromObjectPermissions) {
    System.debug('===============================');
    System.debug('ALL OBJECT-PERMISSIONS');
    System.debug('===============================');
    for (String objectPermission : objectPermissions) {
        System.debug(objectPermission);
    }
}

List<String> missingObjects = new List<String>();
for (String accessibleObject : accessibleObjects) {
    if (!new Set<String>(schemas).contains(accessibleObject.toLowerCase())){
        missingObjects.add(accessibleObject);
    }
}

System.debug('===============================');
System.debug('DIFFERENCE');
System.debug('===============================');
for (String missingObject : missingObjects) {
    System.debug(missingObject);
}
```

Comment: Those objects seems new and would depend on some latest salesforce feature which you woulld need to enable. Documentation [Track Performance with Partner Scorecard](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_scorecard.htm&type=5) says: `Partner scorecards are only available with Partner Community licenses. If you don’t have access to scorecards, contact Salesforce Customer Support to enable Manage Scorecards in your org.` Have you enabled it?\

Comment: I assume they are enabled, since i can create records and can manage the object/field permissions on permissionsets and profiles. But they arn't included in the getGlobalDescribe() Map. We don't use them and don't want to. But this inconsistens is confusing me.

Comment: Are you able to query the records in Apex or SOQL? If yes, then it could be a bug in Salesforce.

Comment: Are you using API 45.0 on the class/page/whatever you're using? Standard sObjects are version dependent.

Comment: If i try to query i get "INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'Scorecard' is not supported." even with the developer console. We are using api version 45.0.